# Can I install ubuntu 32 bit?

Tags: 12.04

My PC have 8gb ram. recent I install ubuntu 32 bit and I saw the system show 8gb. should I install ubuntu 64 bit or 32 bit?

[image: Please review My Pc Info]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend installing the 64-bit version, because you have a 64-bit processor and  more than 4 GB of RAM -- although the RAM is not as much an issue as it used to be since Ubuntu uses PEA (physical address extension -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) by default.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know why the system can saw 8gb.

Comment: Greetings Khanh,

Do you know how much physical RAM you actually have installed in the machine?

Comment: I think 8gb. Just update my screenshot. Please see it

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are wondering why a 32-bit operating system can detect more than 4 GB of RAM? The reason is because Ubuntu uses PEA which allows 32-bit machines to "access a physical address space (including random access memory and memory mapped devices) larger than 4 gigabytes." See [Wikipedia: Physical Address Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) for more information.